# SQL Server calculating dates across months

Tags: .net, sql-server, datetime, range

I am logging my work shifts into Microsoft SQL Server and I want to calculate how much I can expect on my next salary. If my salary was from the 1st to 31st it would not be a problem. The problem is that my payroll goes from the 20th to the 19th and is paid the following month.

I have been successful using this T-SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2013-01-20' AND '2013-02-19'
```

So the T-SQL query makes the extraction from my database as it is supposed to. How do I get the right dates automatically every month? etc. (2013-01-20 and 2013-02-19)

I've been reading about date range, but never found anything that solved my specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define two variables and assign values like this and use in your where clause.

```
SET @startingMonth= CAST(CAST(YEAR(getdate()) AS varchar) + '-' +  CAST(MONTH(getdate()) AS varchar) + '-' + '20' AS DATETIME)

IF(MONTH(getdate())<>12)
  BEGIN
   SET @endMonth= CAST(CAST(YEAR(getdate()) AS varchar) + '-' +  CAST(MONTH(getdate())+1 AS varchar) + '-' + '19' AS DATETIME)
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
   SET @endMonth= CAST(CAST(YEAR(getdate())+1 AS varchar) + '-' +  CAST(1 AS varchar) + '-' + '19' AS DATETIME)
  END
```

Comment: Yes, change of year is handled by checking whether month is 12.